# Convert slider to external javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi I have a slider on a page the updates a number using javascript. I need to put all javascript out of the html to an external js file. Any help is appreciated. Sorry if explanation is not clear. Thanks.

```
<script>
function outputUpdate(n) {
  document.querySelector('.names').value = n;
}
</script>

<form name="infonum">
<textarea rows="3" name="output" onclick="this.select()"></textarea><br />
<input type="button" class="button" value="Go" onclick="populateform(this.form.names.value)"><br />
<input type=range class=rangeInput name="numnames" min=1 value=1 max=15 step=1 oninput="outputUpdate(value)"><br />
<output for=rangeInput class=names>5</output>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new file myjsfile.js and paste all the code (inside  tag). Any external java script files are reference as follows in your html

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javscript" src="myjsfile.js"></script>
....
```

JS file

```
function outputUpdate(n) {
  document.querySelector('.names').value = n;
}
```

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javscript" src="myjsfile.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
<form name="infonum">
<textarea rows="3" name="output" onclick="this.select()"></textarea><br />
<input type="button" class="button" value="Go" onclick="populateform(this.form.names.value)"><br />
<input type=range class=rangeInput name="numnames" min=1 value=1 max=15 step=1 oninput="outputUpdate(value)"><br />
<output for=rangeInput class=names>5</output>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert your javascript into a JavaScript file like script.js(excluding the `<script></script>` tags).

```
<script src="javascript/script.js"></script>
```

If you are unfamiliar with JavaScript, you may want to check out http://www.w3schools.com/js/ or visit http://www.codeacademy.com for a nice interactive tutorial ranging from beginner JavaScript up through AngularJS.

Here is a plunker with a basic example of placing JavaScript in an external source http://plnkr.co/edit/ZOhpzn